# floating layouts spilling over

Tags: javascript, html

Yet another web guy trying to learn floating layouts after using HTML tables for years ...

I am dynamically creating floating divs using a jQuery call.

Each div is constrained by width, height, min-width, min-height, max-width, and max-height. For the most part they line up OK, but sometimes one of the divs will be too short or too long.

If I finagle the page (pop up the ctrl+shft+j in chrome or resize the window) the offending section zips back into place.

Is this a browser shortcoming? Am I dancing on the broken glass of undefined behavior?

```
function createChartsHTML( size ) {
    var htmlString = "";
    for( var i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
            htmlString += '<div id="unit';
            htmlString += i;
            if ( i % 2 == 0 )
                htmlString += '" style="width: 45%; min-width: 45%; max-width: 45%; height: 300px; margin: 0 100; float: left">';           // hammer this one into size!
            else
                htmlString += '" style="width: 45%; min-width: 45%; max-width: 45%; height: 300px; margin: 0 100; float: right">';      // bam !
            htmlString += '</div>';
            if ( (i+1) % 2 == 0 )
                htmlString += '<br style="clear:both">';
    }
    $('#charts_area').html( htmlString );
}
```

Comment: That is a wrong way to add elements to the DOM. See [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-adding-elements/) look for document.createElement(). And note that you can put styles in a CSS file or between <style> tags and don't have to set them on the element.

Comment: WouterH: My problem is this is Ajax-based, and if I dynamically create new divs, how do I clear up the old ones from createElement()? If I use div.html() I can just write the new content there. Where does the .html() strategy run into trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The `max-width` and `min-width` directives are not understood by every browser. As you want the elements to float to a fixes width anyways just define width.
The percentage you give is always to the parent element. So if you did not define the width of the parent (either the page or another div) the browser figures out the width by itself. Some browsers will do that based on the content.
You should also absolutely define the `overflow`-behavior as some browsers extend the `div`s if you did not tell them not to.
Last: don't mix up the `float`-direction as that complicates everything. Just line up elements with the same `float`-direction one after another (in your case 'right' to add each following element right to the preceding one) and they will be ordered that way.

Your style could looke like this:

```
style="width: 45%; min-width: 45%; max-width: 45%; height: 300px; margin: 0 100; float: right;
```

Comment: Some very helpful details here. I can't define the width for the parent container because I have been assigned to use a certain frame work (visualforce) such that it would be an eyesore if it was not resizable (liquid). Maybe I should just do it anyway. Checked out the overflow, but I would probably have picked the default (visible). Pasted your proposed style, but the issue persisted =(